# How to access query string in express while using static?

Tags: express, static

NodeJS Code:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const INDEX = '/public/index.html';

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)
});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    console.log("GET requested.");
    console.log(req.query);
    res.sendFile(INDEX, { root: __dirname });
});
```

URL:
http://localhost:3000/?group=123&team=Test

How do I get the query string while using static?  The get function only seems to be triggered when I comment out the static line.  But without the static line the page doesn't load css/js/imgs.  What am I missing?

Comment: what will you do with that query string? what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I just want to append group, team and timestamp to a log file as a tracking app, but that's down the road, I want to fix this problem first.

Comment: @bdev look below

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ?

Here's the "normal" way to use static

```
app.use('/blah', express.static('some/folder'))
```

**Here's how to use it "conditionally":**

```
app.use('/blah/', async function (req, res, next) {
    
    // for example, get a parameter:
    const c = req.query.city
    const s = req.query.street
    
    // do some calculations
    const okToServeFile = .. your calculations

    if (okToServeFile) {
        express.static('some/folder')(req, res, next)
    }
    else {
        // do something completely different
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        res.status(401).send("expired")
    }
})
```

The secret is this syntax, which I found on an obscure post here on SO

```
 express.static('some/folder')(req, res, next)
```